# Does the SyberJet SJ30 really exist?

Tags: airplane

It is amazing to think about a single-pilot jet with that much range. They have a site, they have some 2 minute videos talking about the aircraft... but there is no video of the thing flying or any review of its interior, no one talking about their experience of owning one...

Does [SyberJet SJ30](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyberJet_SJ30) really exist or is just a project that never made it off the drawing board?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29883/62) is related.

Comment: Going off the Wiki definition, it does exist -- it just might be vapourware. Also worth mentioning that a ~2300nm range for a small-medium-sized twin-engine corporate jet isn't revolutionary; the Citation Excel has about 2150nm, while the newer Longitude boasts _3500nm_, which is actually pretty crazy.

Comment: The Wikipedia page you linked actually includes a list of the various test and production aircraft. There seem to have been at least 9 production aircraft built.

Answer (score 8):

It certainly seems to exist, at least in the sense that *at least one* has been built and registered. The Wikipedia article "[SyberJet SJ30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyberJet_SJ30)" contains [a picture of one](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sino_Swearingen_SJ30-2.jpg).

The registration number on the aircraft pictured is [N7SJ](https://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Results.aspx?NNumbertxt=N7SJ), and the FAA's website says that that aircraft is indeed an SJ30.

Comment: The wikipedia article also claims 8 have been built so far.

Comment: in fact Wikipedia shows (currently) 2 photos of SJ30s in different liveries. While they might depict the same airframe, they might not.

Comment: It looks like 7 SJ30-2s are registered and one SJ30. https://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/AcftRef_Results.aspx?Mfrtxt=&Modeltxt=SJ30&PageNo=1